# discord bot help command doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot but when I do my help command nothing happens.

The code for my help command is:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
    const Embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setColor("YELLOW")
      .setTitle("HardBot - Help")
      .setDescription(":tada: Subscribe to our YouTube channel!")
      .addField("meme", "youtube",true)
    .addField("servers", "ping",true)
    .addField("invite",true)
      .addField("our prefix is h!",true);
    message.channel.send(Embed)
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "help"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to update `discord.js` by using `npm i discord.js@latest` in your terminal. Then replace `RichEmbed` with `MessageEmbed`.

For all changes in `discord.js v12` click [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html).

Edit:
Make sure you fill every field from an embed with values otherwise it is an invalid form body.

Comment: Hey thx for trying to help me but it still didnt work do you know a other way?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @tb3jesica nvm, can you show your index.js?

Comment: add me on discord: luc#4324